# Android: Wait for the longer running process [Timer vs AsyncTask]

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When my app is loading data in an `AsyncTask`, it shows a splash screen. Sometimes this data loading takes under a second and sometimes it takes much longer. However I want to ensure that the splash is up for at least 2 seconds if the data loading finished first, or otherwise wait until the data was done.

My first solution was to use a `Countdown Timer`, and two boolean values. When the processes would start, their booleans would be set to true. When the process was done, it would set it's boolean false. Then it would check if the other's boolean was false, and if it was dismiss the splash.

While this works, I feel like it is overly complicated and was hoping to find a more efficient  or better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to ensure that the splash is up for at least 2 seconds if the
>   data loading finished first, or otherwise wait until the data was
>   done.

You can asyncronously start a Thread(Splash) and AsyncTask for Loading data and call the new Activity on `onPostExecute()` of you AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use `System.getCurrentTime();` To accomplish this?

At the start of the AsyncTask, call that method and store the result.
then, when the task finishes, call the method again and calculate the difference in the time values. If its not greater than 2000 milliseconds, have a while loop that continually requests the system time and compare the values until its equal to or greater than 2 milliseconds.